# Which file descriptor numbers are safe to use in (POSIX) shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, posix, file-descriptors

Chapter [3.6 Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) of the Bash manual says:

> Redirections using file descriptors greater than 9 should be used with care, as they may conflict with file descriptors the shell uses internally.

However, chapter [2.7 Redirection](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07) of the POSIX specs doesn't mention any restrictions on the number, as far as I can see?

What restrictions should I pay attention to, depending on the shell? Can I find out if a file descriptor number is already in use by the shell internally and skip it? What's the largest file descriptor number that I can use?

Comment: If you're asking about POSIX why have you tagged with [tag:bash]?

Answer (score 0):

## Limits.

The limits are OS dependent, and may be affected by commands such as `ulimit`.

## Programming with file descriptors.

### Small projects

Use a convention. Depending on how you look at this, this is why we have 0, 1 and 2 for stdin, stdout and stderr. If you decide for your suite of programs that file descriptor 9 will be used to send events to some kind of pub/sub server then it is up to you to make sure your programs follow this convention. This works pretty well in practice.

### Pass information through the environment or arguments.

GNU make has a `--jobserver-auth=R,W` option (R and W are numbers) which tells you which file descriptors to use with [jobserver](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/POSIX-Jobserver.html) (these days it tends to let you open the named pipe yourself instead of passing in the open file descriptors)

### Let bash choose for you.

If you say

```
    exec {fred}>/tmp/fred.out
    echo hello >&$fred
```

then bash will choose a file descriptor for you and put the value into fred. It will then expand the variable in the second line to cause the `>&` redirection to be to that file descriptor.

Comment: `{fd}>file` is not POSIX sh syntax, that's only available in zsh, ksh93 and bash (new feature  discussed at the time between the implementers of those 3 shells, syntax proposed by a zsh developer).

Comment: Agreed. It is a confusing set of tags, with both "bash" and "posix".

Answer (score 0):

## Best is to let the shell decide

```
exec {somefd}<>myfile
exec {mysock}<>/dev/tcp/192.168.0.5/8888

echo somefd = $somefd
echo my socket file handle = $mysock
# to write to the socket
echo "howdy" >&$mysock
# to read a line back
IFS= read -u $mysock line
echo "$line"

# when done close file handles
exec {somefd}>&-
exec {mysock}>&-
unset somefd mysock

# happy coding
```

Comment: `{fd}<>file` is not POSIX sh syntax, that's only available in zsh, ksh93 and bash. Same for `read -u`. `/dev/tcp/host/port` only  in ksh93 and bash. Leaving those `$var` unquoted only makes sense in zsh.

Comment: Stéphane, you are absolutely correct...